# How to grep exact text using input as a file?

Tags: linux, grep

command used is :

```
grep -f <input_file> <dump_file>
```

Example :
Input_file contains following

```
apple
banana
```

dump_file contains

```
apple
banana
apple_fruit
banana_fruit
```

Objective is to return only `apple` and `banana`.

Comment: Thanks for your question. And for the downvoter: Please leave a comment when downvoting. And if it's because of *RTFM*, please consider [this](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203/rejecting-obvious-questions).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `-x` with `grep` to have the pattern match the whole line:

```
grep -xf <input_file> <dump_file>
```

Example:

```
$ printf "%s\n" apple apple_banana | grep -x apple
apple
```

Comment: Since the title refers to "exact text", maybe you should be using `-F` too?

Comment: ... because try with `ap*ple` as the pattern.

Comment: @Kusalananda I got that, but I don't see a need for it with the current examples.

Comment: This command is not working over input as file where inside input strings are sequential line by line.

Comment: @himanshupandey Please clarify the question and describe what you mean by that last comment.